# How can I reorder parameters with vscode?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, refactoring

I have a simple function whose parameters are unintuitively ordered:

`async blockUser(currentUser: User, userToBlock: User) { ... }`

I would like to (using a proper refactoring tool rather than regexs) refactor the function, and all times the function is called, to reorder the parameters for the new function signature:

`async blockUser(userToBlock: User, currentUser: User) { ... }`

I'd have hoped vsCode would have this in the 'Refactor' menu but can't find it.

[image]

**How can I reorder parameters with vscode?**

Comment: is it just me or is it pretty incredible that VS Code does not have this functionality ?

Answer (score 3):

You can try Shifter extension https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Gruntfuggly.shifter

I'd suggest to use an object as a parameters of the function which will help you to avoid such cases.

```
interface User {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

interface BlockUserParams {
    currentUser: User;
    userToBlock: User;
}

function blockUser({currentUser, userToBlock}: BlockUserParams) {
    console.log(currentUser, userToBlock);
}
```

Comment: Does this also refactor code everywhere where function is used, or just transposes two parameters in place?

Comment: This extension doesn't refactor code. So if the function is already used, call are not updated...

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a proper, built-in method, you can always try a regex replacement like:
`s/(blockUser)\(([^,]+), *([^,]+)\)/\1(\3, \2)/`

Or, in the Find/Replace window:
Replace all `(blockUser)\(([^,]+), *([^,]+)\)`
with `$1($3, $2)`